# Representation of Dirac measure as the derivative of a bounded function whose support is not compact

Tags: distribution-theory

I am studying distributions on my own, and I was wondering if my solution to a question I've been working through looked okay.

*Question. Prove that the Dirac measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equal to a derivative of order $\le n$ of a bounded function (not having compact support). (Treves, 1969, q. 24.7)*

Let
$$
F = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{(-1)^n}{2} & \text{on negative orthant} \\\\[1pt]
\frac{1}{2} & \text{on positive orthant} \\\\[1.2pt]
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Then $F$ is a bounded function not having compact support, and defines a distribution such that for $\varphi\in \mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$:

$$
\begin{align*}
&\langle (F^{\prime},\varphi\rangle
\stackrel{def}{=} \langle F,(-1)^n\varphi ^{\prime}\rangle = (-1)^n\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}F\varphi^{\prime} \\\\
&= (-1)^n\int_{-\infty}^0\cdots\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{(-1)^n}{2}
\varphi^{\prime} +(-1)^n\int_0^{\infty}\cdots\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\varphi^{\prime} \\\\
&= \frac{(-1)^{2n}}{2}\int_{-\infty}^0\cdots\int_{-\infty}^0\varphi^{\prime}+\frac{(-1)^n}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\cdots\int_0^{\infty}\varphi^{\prime} \\\\
&= \frac{(-1)^{2n}}{2}\int_{-\infty}^0\cdots\int_{-\infty}^0\varphi^{\prime}+\frac{(-1)^n}{2}(-1)^n\int_{-\infty}^0\cdots\int_{-\infty}^0\varphi^{\prime}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\varphi(0)+\frac{1}{2}\varphi(0)=\delta_0(\varphi)
\end{align*}
$$

where I’m using $\varphi^{\prime}$ to signify $(\partial/\partial x)^{(1,\cdots , 1)}\varphi$ and  I use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus in the last two lines.

Comment: What does $\partial/\partial x$ mean here?

Comment: Oops. I hope this is clearer now. I waa trying ato find a short way of referring to the function differentiated once with respect to each of its components.

Comment: So it's $(\partial/\partial x_1) \cdots (\partial/\partial x_n)$?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. Treves uses multi-index notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution looks okay. It can be written
$F = \frac{1}{2^n}(\operatorname{sign}\otimes\cdots\otimes\operatorname{sign})$
with derivative
$D = \operatorname{\partial}\otimes\cdots\otimes\operatorname{\partial}$
giving
$$
DF = (\partial\otimes\cdots\otimes\partial)(\frac{1}{2^n}(\operatorname{sign}\otimes\cdots\otimes\operatorname{sign}))
= \frac{1}{2^n}((\partial\operatorname{sign})\otimes\cdots\otimes(\partial\operatorname{sign}))
\\
= \frac{1}{2^n}((2\delta)\otimes\cdots\otimes(2\delta))
= \frac{1}{2^n}2^n(\delta\otimes\cdots\otimes\delta)
= \delta\otimes\cdots\otimes\delta,
$$
which equals the $n$-dimensional delta distribution.

Comment: Yes, that’s nicer. Thanks!